# SmtpClient. Отправка Email

Tags: c#, smtp

Пытаюсь отправить Email, используя SmtpClient. 
Если отправляю на 25 порт, все работает. Если отправляю на 465 порт, получаю GeneralFailure.

Пробовал разные сервера. gmail, mail, yandex. В чем проблема, не понимаю. 
Нужны ли повышенные права?

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("qwert@yandex.ru", "qwert2@yandex.ru");            
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Subject = "Subject";
mail.Body = "Body";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
{
     Host = "smtp.yandex.ru",
     Port = 465,
     EnableSsl = true,
     DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
     UseDefaultCredentials = true,
     Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password")
};       


 try
 {
     client.Send(mail);
 }
 catch (SmtpException ex)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.StatusCode);
 }
```

Comment: А фаервол у вас стоит?

Comment: Фаервола нет, но инет через шлюз. Проверил отправку через программу "10 страйк монитор ", email тестовый отправляется. Но..в wireshark по фильтру SMTP ни чего не отобразилось.

Comment: скорее всего проблема в шлюзе. А какой код вы получаете в консоли?

Comment: Проверю telnet по этим портам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SmtpClient [считается устаревшим](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2), вместо него рекомендуется [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit). Перешел на MailKit, и моя проблема решилась.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с CDO.Message через рефлексию

```
  static void SetCDOProp(object fields, string name, object value) {
    Type t = fields.GetType();
    try { /*create field*/
      t.InvokeMember("Append",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,null,fields, new object[] {name, 12,0,-1});
         } catch {};
    foreach( object item in (System.Collections.IEnumerable)fields) {
        if (t.InvokeMember("name",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, item, null).ToString().Contains(name)) 
           t.InvokeMember("value",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, item, new object[] {value});            
        }}


  static void Main() {
       Type TMsg=Type.GetTypeFromProgID("CDO.Message");
       object Msg = TMsg.InvokeMember(null,System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance,null,null,null);
       object conf= TMsg.InvokeMember("Configuration",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty,null,Msg,null);
       object fields=TMsg.InvokeMember("Fields",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty,null,conf,null);             
       SetCDOProp(fields,"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing",2);
       SetCDOProp(fields,"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver","127.0.0.1");
       SetCDOProp(fields,"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configurationsmtpauthenticate",0);
       SetCDOProp(fields,"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername","test@test.ru");
      //SetCDOProp(fields,"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword","***");
      //SetCDOProp(fields,"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport",465); 

       TMsg.InvokeMember("Update",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,null,fields,null);
       TMsg.InvokeMember("To",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty,null,Msg,new object[]{"test@test.ru"});
       TMsg.InvokeMember("From",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty,null,Msg,new object[]{"test@test.ru"});
       TMsg.InvokeMember("Subject",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty,null,Msg,new object[]{"test"});
       TMsg.InvokeMember("TextBody",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty,null,Msg,new object[]{"test"});
       TMsg.InvokeMember("Send",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,null,Msg,null);

   }
```

Параметры можно использовать такие

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/autopromotebodyparts"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/flushbuffersonwrite"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/httpcookies"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/languagecode"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/nntpaccountname"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/nntpauthenticate"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/nntpconnectiontimeout"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/nntpserver"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/nntpserverpickupdirectory"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/nntpserverport"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/nntpusessl"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/postemailaddress"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/postpassword"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/postusername"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/postuserreplyemailaddress"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/postusing"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/savesentitems"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendemailaddress"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/senduserreplyemailaddress"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpaccountname"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverpickupdirectory"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/urlgetlatestversion"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/urlproxybypass"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/urlproxyserver"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/usemessageresponsetext"
```

Страница от microsoft
http://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/310212/how-to-use-the-cdosys-dll-library-to-send-an-e-mail-message-with-attac

Параметры детально
http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/exchange-server/exchange-10/ms526288(v%3Dexchg.10)

Comment: То же разработка микрософта, наверно они забыли про CDO упоминая MailKit